# difference between http://schema.openid.net/contact/email and http://axschema.org/contact/email

Tags: openid, openid-provider

when to use http://schema.openid.net/contact/email and when to use   http://axschema.org/contact/email in openid request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no standard schema for Attribute Exchange (AX).  But the axschema.org seems to be the closest thing to it.  To know which one to use, the best way I know of is to look for a "hint" about which schema(s) are supported in the OP's XRDS document.  DotNetOpenAuth does this, for example, and has a good success rate. When the XRDS doesn't contain *any* of the AX schema URIs, you can send all three (yes, [there are three](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/03/how-to-pretty-much-guarantee-that-you.html)) AX attribute URI formats to best ensure a useful response.

Comment: What would those "hints" in XRDS look like?

Comment: A TypeURI in the XRDS that contains any of the AX attributes the OP supports.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it seems the preferred AX schema url is always schema.openid.net. The axschema.org domain has been down for almost a year (not that it's needed).

Refs: [Chris Messina on OpenID list](http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-board/2011-May/005160.html) and [StackOverflow: Google only responds to schema.openid.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960389/146620).