# List of available attributes for http://axschema.org and http://schemas.openid.net

Tags: openid, schema, google-openid, openid-provider

I have searched high, low, far and wide but can not find anything on the Internet that lists the available attributes for these schemas. Does anyone know where the documentation is for these? so far I know of:

http://axschema.org/namePerson/first

http://axschema.org/namePerson/last

http://axschema.org/contact/email

http://schemas.openid.net/ax/api/user_id

Comment: [The list is here for Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OpenID-General-Discussion/Get-Fetch-email-and-other-profile-info/1272016054000-0dfe8736-5c46-3c83-a4ac-c38d25722e3b) which still uses axschema

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well I cannot see axschema.org online anymore. But based on http://groups.google.com/group/axschema/browse_thread/thread/49312a23a7d5ecce# I think [http://openid.net/schema] superseeds [http://axschema.org].

Here is the list, also on http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-properties-list-1_0-01.html.

```
http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/prefix
http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/first
http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/last
http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/middle
http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/suffix
http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/friendly
http://openid.net/schema/person/guid
http://openid.net/schema/birthDate/birthYear
http://openid.net/schema/birthDate/birthMonth
http://openid.net/schema/birthDate/birthday
http://openid.net/schema/gender
http://openid.net/schema/language/pref
http://openid.net/schema/contact/phone/default
http://openid.net/schema/contact/phone/home
http://openid.net/schema/contact/phone/business
http://openid.net/schema/contact/phone/cell
http://openid.net/schema/contact/phone/fax
http://openid.net/schema/contact/postaladdress/home
http://openid.net/schema/contact/postaladdressadditional/home
http://openid.net/schema/contact/city/home
http://openid.net/schema/contact/state/home
http://openid.net/schema/contact/country/home
http://openid.net/schema/contact/postalcode/home
http://openid.net/schema/contact/postaladdress/business
http://openid.net/schema/contact/postaladdressadditional/business
http://openid.net/schema/contact/city/business
http://openid.net/schema/contact/state/business
http://openid.net/schema/contact/country/business
http://openid.net/schema/contact/postalcode/business
http://openid.net/schema/contact/IM/default
http://openid.net/schema/contact/IM/AIM
http://openid.net/schema/contact/IM/ICQ
http://openid.net/schema/contact/IM/MSN
http://openid.net/schema/contact/IM/Yahoo
http://openid.net/schema/contact/IM/Jabber
http://openid.net/schema/contact/IM/Skype
http://openid.net/schema/contact/internet/email
http://openid.net/schema/contact/web/default
http://openid.net/schema/contact/web/blog
http://openid.net/schema/contact/web/Linkedin
http://openid.net/schema/contact/web/Amazon
http://openid.net/schema/contact/web/Flickr
http://openid.net/schema/contact/web/Delicious
http://openid.net/schema/company/name
http://openid.net/schema/company/title
http://openid.net/schema/media/spokenname
http://openid.net/schema/media/greeting/audio
http://openid.net/schema/media/greeting/video
http://openid.net/schema/media/biography
http://openid.net/schema/media/image
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/16x16
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/32x32
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/48x48
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/64x64
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/80x80
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/128x128
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/160x120
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/320x240
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/640x480
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/120x160
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/240x320
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/480x640
http://openid.net/schema/media/image/favicon
http://openid.net/schema/timezone
```

Comment: Drupal has a demo plugin at http://drupal.org/project/openid_ax which implements these properties.

Comment: @Christian it seems you are. The URLs like http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/prefix are not supposed to work they are basically names formatted as URLs to make them unique. Please checkout the links in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am unclear how you determined that the *openid.net* identifiers supersede the *ax* identifiers.  It looks like nobody ever answered Andrew Arnott on Google Groups. Preferring to go with one set of identifiers, I am going to see how far I can get with specifying *openid.net* in my requests.

Comment: I'm sorry but this was a couple of years ago so I do not remember. It seems the axschema.org domain was never renewed so it was taken offline. Also google only works with openid: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9235519/328808

Comment: Some providers, e.g. Google and myOpenID, looks to be using http://schema.openid.net/xxx rather than http://openid.net/schema/xxx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Natan Cox' list, Yahoo! also gives the full name out via

```
http://axschema.org/namePerson
```