# OmniAuth & openid: getting certain fields from openid provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, omniauth

I'm using the rails gem: OmniAuth to login users.

When using an OpenId provider I would like to get certain field, like email and nickname but I don't see any documentation on this.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking how to request for that data, or how to ensure you get it?  You can request for data using the OpenID AX attributes, but an OpenID provider isn't obliged to respond to what you request for. This should be of some help though:

[Retrieve OpenID AX attributes from Google / Yahoo in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956522/retrieve-openid-ax-attributes-from-google-yahoo-in-rails)

It seems like Google will respond with an email only to

```
http://schema.openid.net/contact/email
```

whereas Yahoo will reply to

```
http://axschema.org/contact/email
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this Railscast (towards the end)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2) by Ryan Bates useful for capturing an email address when authenticating via OpenID. For other available fields, I guess you can add something of the following to your authentications controller when making the authentication request

```
# authentications_controller.rb
...
def create
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  raise omniauth.to_yaml
  ...
end
...
```

and then log in via openID and see what options you have.

Comment: That won't work - not many options are available by default with openid.  The question is how to make them available, not how to retrieve them from request.env.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Guess I misunderstood :/

Answer (score 1):

There's some instructions for this under the "Google" openID section in the Devise omniauth integration docs:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Look for the class method `find_for_open_id` in the User model and the controller subclass `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController` for how the data is passed through from the `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` hash. This relates to any OpenID strategy, not just the Google one.

In terms of customising exactly which attributes you ask for from the OpenID provider, you might be best to make your own clone of the `omniauth_openid` gem or subclass it and change the `options`. (See: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb )

Answer (score 0):

request.env['omniauth.auth'] should have what you need. For Twitter it returns something like

```
{
  'uid' => '12356',
  'provider' => 'twitter',
  'user_info' => {
    'name' => 'User Name',
    'nickname' => 'username',
    # ...
  }
}
```

Just inspect it for openid.

Comment: what it returns for twitter and openid are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

request.env['omniauth.auth'] will contain the entire response from the callback. But not all providers return the user email(twitter won't). OpenID via google or yahoo should have email as part of 'user_info' hash.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure `omniauth` in your initialization block, you can override any of the options, including required and optional fields. As per the docs, use the `Builder` to get what you need configured. EG:

```
config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
        provider :open_id, :name => 'my_provider',
                 :identifier => 'https://myprovider.com/openid/xrds',
                 :required => ['http://axschema.org/namePerson/first','http://axschema.org/namePerson/last','http://axschema.org/contact/email','http://axschema.org/my_provider/some_field']
    end
```